# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты, jest

подскажите как решить проблему с тестами
мой основной js (activeBtnClick.js):

```
export default function activeButtonClick(button) {
 if (button.classList.contains('active')) {
  button.classList.remove('active');
 } else {
  button.classList.add('active');
 }
}
```

activeBtnClick.test.js - тест:

```
const activeButtonClick = require('./activeBtnClick');

describe("activeBtnClick", () => {
 const pencil = document.createElement('div');
 activeButtonClick(pencil);
 it("add class to the button", () => {
  expect(pencil.classList.contains('active')).toEqual(true);
 });
});
```

**jest.config.js НЕТУ**
**babel НЕ использую**
**использую webpack**
package.json:

```
{
  "name": "simple-piskel-clone",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple Piskel Clone",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "build": "webpack",
   "watch": "webpack --watch",
   "test": "jest"
},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
   "css-loader": "^3.4.0",
   "eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",
   "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
   "jest": "^24.9.0",
   "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
   "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
   "style-loader": "^1.1.1",
   "url-loader": "^3.0.0",
   "webpack": "^4.41.4",
   "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "eslint": "^6.8.0",
   "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.0.0",
   "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.19.1"
  }
}
```

ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _«НЕ использую использую webpack»_ - `"build": "webpack", "watch": "webpack --watch",` ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: @yar85 ,поправил

Comment: Что-то меня совсем запутал код в вопросе, хотя все так просто с виду (похоже, недопереотдыхал, раз читаю "describe" как AMDшный "define" :D)... Сейчас вроде уловил суть, и исправил ответ. _/* но он на уровне предположения, так как сам юзаю babel-jest */_

Comment: Откатил правку - не заменяй суть вопроса (см. правила), *дополняй* ее.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, Jest без Babel не понимает ESM (`import` и `export` это синтаксис ECMAScript Modules) - тогда, в синтаксисе CommonJS будет так:

```
module.exports = function activeButtonClick() {...}
```

```
const activeButtonClick = require('./activeBtnClick.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

Для меня сработало вот так.

```sh
npx mocha --require ts-node/register --require esm src/**/*.spec.ts
```

Или `package.json` scripts (оба варианта работают, используйте тот который больше нравится):

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha -r esm -r ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "test-ts": "ts-mocha -r esm -p tsconfig.json src/**/*.spec.ts"
}
```

Главное не забыть добавить `esm` в `devDependencies`:

```
npm install --save-dev esm
```

Чтобы в package.json было

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "esm": "^3.2.25"
}
```

Если использовать `ts-mocha` то её так же нужно добавить в `package.json`.